# How to create a unique array in mongodb aggregation pipeline by preserving the order

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to solve one use case. In aggregation pipeline need to create a unique array of one field by preserving the order by sorting the documents.

$addtoset creates a unique array but order is not preserved where as push preserves order but duplicates are allowed. How to deal this scenario?

Example:
Input documents in collection

```sh
{
studentid: 1,
createddate: 2020-05-24
exam:english
}

{
studentid: 1,
createddate: 2020-05-25
exam: maths
}

{
studentid: 1,
createddate: 2020-05-26
exam:physics
}

{
studentid: 1,
createddate: 2020-05-27
exam:maths
}

{
studentid: 1,
createddate: 2020-05-28
exam:chemistry
}
```

Expected output:

```sh
{
studentid:1,
exam:[chemistry,maths,physiscs,english]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want first $push all of the values into an array, then use $addFields and $reduce the array to build an array of unique values.

```
{$addFields:{
     outputarray:{
        $reduce:{
            input:"$inputArray",
            initialValue:[],
            in:{
              $cond:{
                  if: {$in: [ "$$this", "$$value"]},
                  then: "$$value",
                  else: {$concatArrays:["$$value",["$$this"]]}
              }
           }
        }
    }
}}
```